# How do I create a dataset with all entries in each row in R?

Tags: r, formatting, dataset, subset

Say I have a large dataset, and the information is organized based on a type of entry, and the amount of occurrences of that type of entry.

Say...

```
   Area        Animal                              Observations       
   US           Cat                                   4
   NE           Cat                                   9
   US           Dog                                   2
```

My question is how would I create a dataset (to do analysis in R) that would list the items like...

Say...

```
   Area        Animal      
    US            Cat
    US            Cat
    US            Cat...
    US
    NE
    NE
    NE
    NE....
    US..          Dog..
```

I'm asking because I have a large data set and I'm trying to get each entry for each row, rather them being grouped. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
library(splitstackshape)
expandRows(df1, 'Observations')
#   Area Animal
#1     US    Cat
#1.1   US    Cat
#1.2   US    Cat
#1.3   US    Cat
#2     NE    Cat
#2.1   NE    Cat
#2.2   NE    Cat
#2.3   NE    Cat
#2.4   NE    Cat
#2.5   NE    Cat
#2.6   NE    Cat
#2.7   NE    Cat
#2.8   NE    Cat
#3     US    Dog
#3.1   US    Dog
```

Comment: Incredibly! Thank you so much for being so quick!

Answer (score 1):

Index the dataframe by 'rownames' repeated as many times as 'Observations':

```
> rep(rownames(dat), dat$Observations)
 [1] "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "3" "3"

> dat[ rep(rownames(dat), dat$Observations) , ]
    Area Animal Observations
1     US    Cat            4
1.1   US    Cat            4
1.2   US    Cat            4
1.3   US    Cat            4
2     NE    Cat            9
2.1   NE    Cat            9
2.2   NE    Cat            9
2.3   NE    Cat            9
2.4   NE    Cat            9
2.5   NE    Cat            9
2.6   NE    Cat            9
2.7   NE    Cat            9
2.8   NE    Cat            9
3     US    Dog            2
3.1   US    Dog            2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `lapply()` and `rep()`:

```
df <- data.frame(Area=c('US','NE','US'), Animal=c('Cat','Cat','Dog'), Observations=c(4,9,2) );
as.data.frame(lapply(df[-3],rep,df[,3]));
##    Area Animal
## 1    US    Cat
## 2    US    Cat
## 3    US    Cat
## 4    US    Cat
## 5    NE    Cat
## 6    NE    Cat
## 7    NE    Cat
## 8    NE    Cat
## 9    NE    Cat
## 10   NE    Cat
## 11   NE    Cat
## 12   NE    Cat
## 13   NE    Cat
## 14   US    Dog
## 15   US    Dog
```